# how to use custom icon with 2 color in tabor in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, icons, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I want to add special icon with 2 color in the tab bar but the app detect just one color I used lots of single color icons and there is no problem with them but this icon won't show as I want to be 
here is the image of that Icon 
[image: here is the image]

the tabor background is white

Answer (score 2):

try to use .jpg of the image in place of .png

Answer (score 0):

If you are using image assets then change the render option as Original Image instead of Default.

[image]

Otherwise change the tint color of tabor to clear.

Comment: doesn't worked so I think there is no way because I didn't seen such thing

Answer (score 0):

Try to set color you want using this code.

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .red
```

Or you can tell the system to keep the original rendering mode, so it does not use default colors. Set image like that.

```
... = UIImage(named:"myImage.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```